# How to get binding for RadioButton GroupName in a nested ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I want to display a list of questions and answers. Each question should have its own possible answers list displayed as a radio button group. Right now all the radio buttons across all the questions are behaving as one group, which means I can only select one answer from the entire list of questions. Here's what I have so far. Not sure if I'm using the RelativeSource property right.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why image came out so small. Apologies. If you right-click View Image (Firefox) it will be bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `RelativeSource` correctly, except for one detail -- you want to bind to the `DataContext`, not the `ItemsControl` itself.  Presumably "QuestionGroupName" is a property of the view-model, along with "Question" and "AnswersList", right?  So this should work:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="{Binding DataContext.QuestionGroupName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" />
```